# How to pass body to passport-local?

Tags: mongodb, express, mongoose, passport.js, passport-local

I'm following some video course where they show me how to use Passport for Google OAuth, and at the end they're just like "Welp, now you can use all the strategies! Have fun!"

So I tried to implement passport-local like so:

```
// passport.js
// ...
passport.use(
  new LocalStrategy((username, password, done) => {
    User
      .findOne({ username, password })
      .then(userFromDB => {
        if (userFromDB) {
          done(null, userFromDB) // No errs so return the user from db
        } else {
          new User({
            username,
            password,
          })
            .save() // Add user to our db
            .then(userFromDB => done(null, userFromDB)) // return user from db
        }
      })
  })
)
// ...

// routes.js
// ...
app.post(`/auth/local`,
  passport.authenticate(`local`, {
    failureRedirect: `/api/v1/current_user`,
  }),
  (req, res) => res.send(`It worked`)
)
// ...
```

My question is how does `new LocalStrategy((username, password, done) ...` get the `username` and `password`?

This is an Express server with Mongo.

Answer (score 0):

```
 app.post('/login', 
      passport.authenticate('local', { failureRedirect: '/login' }),
      function(req, res) {
        res.redirect('/');
      });
```

> here when you hit route `/login` then  `passport.authenticate('local'`
>   automatically call function `passport.use(new LocalStrategy(` .in
>   route login from front end side you need to send username and password

```
passport.use(
  new LocalStrategy((username, password, done) => {
    User
      .findOne({ username, password })
      .then(userFromDB => {
        if (userFromDB) {
          done(null, userFromDB) // No errs so return the user from db
        } else {
          new User({
            username,
            password,
          })
            .save() // Add user to our db
            .then(userFromDB => done(null, userFromDB)) // return user from db
        }
      })
  })
)
```

Comment: Yes, but _how_ do I "from front end side you need to send username and password"?

Comment: for testing purpose, you can username and password from [postman](https://www.getpostman.com/)
for example https://sitecore-community.github.io/docs/images/SitecoreServicesClient/Postman_login.png